# Ubuntu 12.04.5 server VM [Stopping Mount filesystem on boot]

Tags: server, apache2, lamp

I am running a Ubuntu 12.04.5 server as a web server, I am using LAMP stack packages to preform my web application requirements.

I had the web application hanging, so I restarted my LAMP stack packages to refresh, but nothing made it better. I decided to run *Sudo Rebot*, to clear RAM and get back on business, here is where I got the following screen: 
[Screenshot of my VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WDiB.png)

can you help me with this please?